# Finding out who started a conversation, by analysing the skype screenshots - python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, tesseract

I was analysing skype screenshots. The task at hand is to find out from the **available chat screenshot** who said what in the current conversation and at what time.

If I just run an ocr engine on the image it gives me no value as to **who said what** from the available text.

```
img = requests.get(url)
if img.status_code == 200:
    img = Image.open(StringIO(img.content))
    img = process_image(img)
    img = img.resize((int(img.size[0] * 2), int(img.size[1] * 2)),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

The text here will just give me all the text content from the skype window but I am not able to identify as to who said what.

**The only prominent distinctive detail observable is that my message is highlighted in a blue rectangle and the ones I receive are in grey.**

**How can I identify who sent, what message, and at what time?**

To make a little bit more sense as to why I am doing this; I further plan to analyse the text extracted from the screenshot and categorise into two different types of the conversations(whether I started the conversation, or someone else).

For Example: - 
If this is the skype screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-oewG7CW8ozTWx4U280bEFqY1E

According to the last message and timestamp, I sent a message which started a conversation.

For this other Example: - if this is the screenshot
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-oewG7CW8ozaE1kS3dKUU4wMHc

The other person started the conversation.

[EDIT]: I am really sorry that I forgot to mention that I do not have access to the skype chat logs. I just have a huge list of skype screenshots that I need to analyse.

Comment: Doesn't Skype store chat logs as a text file somehow on your computer? I'm not sure what the format that they use looks like but you could open the text file and see if you can parse it to obtain that information. Like I said, i'm not 100% sure if this can get what you want, but it's just an idea that came to mind.

Comment: What code have you written and where _specifically_ are you stuck?

Comment: At least Linux skype stores the messages in sqlite3 database - you won't even need OCR.

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather use skype's database file.

The `main.db` file actually contains these conversations, and, has all the information you want.

Using a simple sql query you'll get what you want in no time.

```
sqlite3 path/to/main.db "select * from messages where dialog_partner=\"partnerusername\";"
```

Comment: I do not have access to skype logs. I am analysing skype screenshots from different users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe skype automatically keeps chat logs on your computer somewhere. You can open the file and parse through it to find the information that pertains to you.

I don't have any chat logs on computer as i'm at work and don't have skype installed on this computer, but I know that if you copy and paste your chat into a text file it will look something like this:

```
[0:00:00 AM] user1: xxxxxxx
[0:00:00 AM] user2: xxxxxxx
```

I'm not 100% sure if that's exactly how it will look, as i'm working off memory right now. Of course this is just a template. It will show the time stamp of the message, the user's name, and their message.

To determine who started the conversation, you could read the file and parse the lines, specifically looking at the time stamps. I'm sure you could find something that way to help you out. Maybe you could find instances where there are large gaps of time between 2 messages, and whichever message came first could determine who started the conversation. I don't know if that will be a good factor to make the assumption for you, but i'm sure you'll be able to come to a conclusion somehow.

Comment: I do not have access to the skype chat logs. Just access to the skype screenshots.